# Encoding of the spellfile en.utf-8.add

Tags: encoding

When I open my private spellfile `en.utf-8.add`, words containing
unusual characters, such as pœësis, are rendered incorrectly;
in this case, pÅÃ«sis.  At the bottom of the screen it says
`[converted]`, and `:set` shows that the fileencoding is latin1.
What is happening here and how can I have vim render such words
correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reopening the file and forcing it to load in "utf-8" mode. You can do this with

```
:e! ++enc=utf-8 %
```

From `:help ++opt`

```
                            *++opt* *[++opt]*
The [++opt] argument can be used to force the value of 'fileformat',
'fileencoding' or 'binary' to a value for one command, and to specify the
behavior for bad characters.  The form is: >
    ++{optname}
Or: >
    ++{optname}={value}

Where {optname} is one of:      *++ff* *++enc* *++bin* *++nobin* *++edit*
    ff     or  fileformat   overrides 'fileformat'
    enc    or  encoding     overrides 'fileencoding'
    bin    or  binary       sets 'binary'
    nobin  or  nobinary     resets 'binary'
    bad             specifies behavior for bad characters
    edit            for |:read| only: keep option values as if editing
                a file
```

I would also recommend adding

```
set encoding=utf8
set fenc=utf8
```

to your `.vimrc` if you have not already done so.

Comment: Thanks! turns out the conversion happened because I had some Greek words in there.

Comment: @Toothrot Glad I could help!